# Bootsrap "page-scroll" class doesn't work in Modals

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a website using bootstrap.
The "page-scroll" perfectly works when on the page itself.

```
<a href="#nav" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Start</a>
```

The line of code above perfectly scrolls with the intended animation to the code below.

```
<section class="bg-primary" id="nav">
```

My problem is that, I cannot make the "page-scroll" work inside a **Modal**.
Is it possible to make this work or we can't do this animation effect inside a Modal?

Edit: This fiddle is originally from @Raki. I modified it to have the code that I want to use inside the Modal. http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1495/

Comment: if you upload your code in fiddle it will be helpful to solve it

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1495/

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh_V_R/3kgbG/1488/ where 
class `.modal-container` contains

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: I need "page-scroll" animation effect to work on something like this inside the modal http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1495/